# How can i add a link to notyjs text message

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to put a link in a message that im sending using notyjs (http://needim.github.io/noty/). I don't want to use a noty button, just a link.

```
var n = noty({text: 'Hi there click, <a href="http://somehere.com">here</a> to continue'});
```

The problem is that the message shows with the link, but when i click. it does nothing.

any ideas? thanks

Comment: try this

`var n = noty({text: 'Hi there click,'+ <a href="http://somehere.com">here</a>+' to continue'});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `noty` closes on clicking anywhere in the container. To prevent this you should change the `closeWith` parameter. The modified code is as below.

```
var n = noty({text: 'Hi there click, <a href="http://somehere.com">here</a> to continue',closeWith:['button']});
```

JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nGDvU/